# Append output of Find command to Variable in Bash Script

Tags: linux, bash, find

Trying to append output of find command to a variable in a Bash script

Can append output of find command to a log file ok, but can't append it to a variable i.e.

This works ok:

```
find $DIR -type d -name "*" >> $DIRS_REMOVED_LOG
```

But this won't:

```
FILES_TO_EVAL=find $DIR -type f \( -name '*.sh' -or -name '*.txt' -or -name '*.xml' -or -name '*.log' \)

ENV=`basename $PS_CFG_HOME | tr "[:lower:]" "[:upper:]"`

FILE_TYPES=(*.log *.xml *.txt *.sh)
DIRS_TO_CLEAR="$PS_CFG_HOME/data/files   $PS_CFG_HOME/appserv/prcs/$ENV/files   $PS_CFG_HOME/appserv/prcs/$ENV/files/CQ"

FILES_REMOVED_LOG=$PS_CFG_HOME/files_removed.log
DIRS_REMOVED_LOG=$PS_CFG_HOME/dirs_removed.log

##Cycle through directories
##Below for files_removed_log works ok but can't get the find into a variable.
for DIR in `echo $DIRS_TO_CLEAR`
do
        echo "Searching $DIR for files:"
        FILES_TO_EVAL=find $DIR -type f \( -name '*.sh' -or -name '*.txt' -or -name '*.xml' -or -name '*.log' \)

        find $DIR -type d -name "*" >> $DIRS_REMOVED_LOG
done
```

Expected `FILES_TO_EVAL` to be populated with results of `find` command but it is empty.

Answer (score 3):

Run your scripts through [ShellCheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/). It finds lots of common mistakes, much like a compiler would.

```
FILES_TO_EVAL=find $DIR -type f \( -name '*.sh' -or -name '*.txt' -or -name '*.xml' -or -name '*.log' \)
```

> SC2209: Use `var=$(command)` to assign output (or quote to assign string).

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the problems that [shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net) will point out, there are a number of subtler problems.

For one thing, you're using all-caps variable names. This is dangerous, because there are a large number of all-caps variables that have special meanings to the shell and/or other tools, and if you accidentally use one of those, it can have weird effects. Lower- or mixed-case variables are much safer (except when you specifically *want* the special meaning).

Also, you should almost always put double-quotes around variable references (e.g. `find "$dir" ...` instead of `find $dir ...`). Without them, the variables will be subject to word splitting and wildcard expansion, which can have a variety of unintended consequences. In some cases, you *need* word splitting and/or wildcard expansion on a variable's value, but usually not quite the way the shell does it; in these cases, you should look for a better way to do the job.

In the line that's failing,

```
FILES_TO_EVAL=find $DIR -type f \( -name '*.sh' -or -name '*.txt' -or -name '*.xml' -or -name '*.log' \)
```

the immediate problem is that you need to use `$(find ...)` to capture the output from the `find` command. But this is still dangerous, because it's just storing a newline-delimited list of file paths, and the standard way to expand this (just using an unquoted variable reference) has all the problems I mentioned above. In this case, it will lead to trouble if any filenames contain spaces or wildcards (which are perfectly legal in filenames). In you're in a controlled environment where you can guarantee this won't happen, you'll get away with it... but it's really not the best idea.

Correctly handling a list of filepaths from `find` is a little complicated, but there are a number of ways to do it. There's a lot of good info in [BashFAQ #20: "How can I find and safely handle file names containing newlines, spaces or both?"](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/020) I'll summarize some common options below:

If you don't need to store the list, just run commands on individual files, you can use `find -exec`:

```
find "$dir" -type f \( -name '*.sh' -or -name '*.txt' -or -name '*.xml' -or -name '*.log' \) -exec somecommand {} \;
```

If you need to run something more complex, you can use `find -print0` to output the list in an unambiguous form, and then use `read -d ''` to read them. There are a bunch of potential pitfalls here, so here's the version I use to avoid all the trouble spots:

```
while IFS= read -r -d '' filepath <&3; do
    dosomethingwith "$filepath"
done 3< <(find "$dir" -type f \( -name '*.sh' -or -name '*.txt' -or -name '*.xml' -or -name '*.log' \) -print0)
```

Note that the `<(command)` syntax (known as process substitution) is a bash-only feature, so use an explicit bash shebang (`#!/bin/bash` or `#!/usr/bin/env bash`) on your script, and don't override it by running the script with `sh`.

If you really do need to store the list of paths for later, store it as an array:

```
files_to_eval=()
while IFS= read -r -d '' filepath; do
    files_to_eval+=("$filepath")
done < <(find "$dir" -type f \( -name '*.sh' -or -name '*.txt' -or -name '*.xml' -or -name '*.log' \) -print0)
```

..or, if you have bash v4.4 or later, it's easier to use `readarray` (aka `mapfile`):

```
readarray -td '' files_to_eval < <(find "$dir" -type f \( -name '*.sh' -or -name '*.txt' -or -name '*.xml' -or -name '*.log' \) -print0)
```

In either case, you should then expand the array with `"${files_to_eval[@]}"` to get all the elements without subjecting them to word splitting and wildcard expansion.

On to some other problems. In this line:

```
FILE_TYPES=(*.log *.xml *.txt *.sh)
```

In this context, the wildcards will be expanded immediately to a list of matches in the current director. You should quote them to prevent this:

```
file_types=("*.log" "*.xml" "*.txt" "*.sh")
```

In these lines:

```
DIRS_TO_CLEAR="$PS_CFG_HOME/data/files   $PS_CFG_HOME/appserv/prcs/$ENV/files   $PS_CFG_HOME/appserv/prcs/$ENV/files/CQ"
...
for DIR in `echo $DIRS_TO_CLEAR`
```

You're storing a list as a single string with entries separated by spaces, which has all the word-split and wildcard problems I've been harping on. Also, the `echo` here is a complication that doesn't do anything useful, and actually makes the wildcard problem worse. Use an array, and avoid all the mess:

```
dirs_to_clear=("$ps_cfg_home/data/files" "$ps_cfg_home/appserv/prcs/$env/files" "$ps_cfg_home/appserv/prcs/$env/files/CQ")
...
for dir in "${dirs_to_clear[@]}"
```